# How to have different implementations for generic structs based on traits in Rust?

Tags: rust

Say I have a `Pair<T>` wrapper that wraps two instance of a same type `T`.

```rust
struct Pair<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T
}
```

`Pair<T>` has a method called `swap` that swaps between `x` and `y`. I want an implementation that if the type `T` is "fast-swappable", that is, `T` implements the trait `FastSwap`, then the `swap` implementation will call `fast_swap`.

```rust
trait FastSwap<T> {
    fn fast_swap(self: &mut Self, other: &mut T);
}

impl <T: FastSwap<T>> Pair<T> {
    fn swap(&mut self) {
        self.x.fast_swap(&mut self.y);
    }
}
```

Also, if `T` doesn't implement `FastSwap`, there should be a fallback option using `std::mem::swap`.

```rust
impl <T: !FastSwap<T>> Pair<T> {
    fn swap(&mut self) {
        std::mem::swap(&mut self.x, &mut self.y);
    }
}
```

However, the Rust complier complains that I can't use `!FastSwap` here. How to make the syntax correct? And also why `!FastSwap` is forbidden here?

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed Yes, partially. I would also like to know why I can't use `! Trait` here. Or maybe I'd better open another question to ask that?

Comment: The reason you can't use `!Trait` which is known as [negative impls](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/negative-impls.html), is because the example you gave is not yet supported.

Comment: @vallentin So, it's because the functionality has not yet been implemented, but not for some other theoretical reason, e.g. it will create an undecidable problem. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: As far as I recall, "negative impls" or more specifically "negative bounds", are simply not supported yet. But what you're trying to do makes sense. However, you can augment it using specialization as Ibraheem linked to.

Comment: With the specialization feature, you do not need an implementation for `Trait` and one for `!Trait`. Instead, you have a `default` implementation, and then a specialized implementation for `Trait`.